# RestKit foreign key relationship mapping not added

Tags: foreign-key-relationship, restkit-0.20

I few questions regarding RestKit and foreign key relationship mapping.

Before starting with my questions here is what is in place and working properly.

1. Core Data model

[image: Data model]

Favorite has the following attributes :

placeIds: transformable type that hold the place ids that are define as user's favorite places.

2. RestKit

a. User data mapping

```
RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[self entityName]
                                                     inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id":@"userId"}];
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userId" ];
[entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"favorites" toKeyPath:@"favorites" withMapping:[AOFavorite mapping]]];

[entityMapping setAssignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes:YES];
[entityMapping setAssignsNilForMissingRelationships:YES];
```

b. Favorite Data mapping

```
RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[self entityName]
                                                     inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"placeIds":@"placeIds"}];
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userId" ];
[entityMapping addConnection:[AOFavorite placesConnection]];

[entityMapping setAssignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes:YES];
[entityMapping setAssignsNilForMissingRelationships:YES];

+ (RKConnectionDescription *)placesConnection
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[self entityName]
                                              inManagedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
    NSRelationshipDescription *places = [entity relationshipsByName][@"places"];
    return [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:places attributes:@{ @"placeIds": @"placeId" }];
}
```

c. Place Data mapping

```
RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[self entityName]
                                                     inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id":@"placeId"}];
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"placeId" ];

[entityMapping setAssignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes:YES];
[entityMapping setAssignsNilForMissingRelationships:YES];
```

User entity has the logged in user object correctly fit into persistent store.

Since the API provide User's favorite places with an array of ids, they are stored into User > Favorite > placeIds

--

I'm using the following method to request the API's object for the Favorite's place relationship with the Route defined as is:

```
[[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] router] routeSet] addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithRelationshipName:@"favorite/places"
                                                                                     objectClass:[AOFavorite class]
                                                                                     pathPattern:@"user/favorite/places"
                                                                                          method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:@"favorite/places"
                                                        ofObject:[[AOUser currentUser] favorites]
                                                      parameters:nil
                                                         success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                                                         } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                                         }];
```

3. Problem and question

a. getObjectsAtPathForRelationship has the places correctly created into the Place entity but the Favorite > Place relationship isn't linked.

b. what is the purpose of having the placeIds into Favorite entities. I have seen SO question/response regarding Foreign key mapping stating that this is the way to do it. Can someone explained why ?

Comment: A picture of your data model is much easier to read than a text description... You need to tell RestKit to use the `placeIds` to connect the relationship - have you done that anywhere? The relationship route just goes and gets content.

Comment: @wain: I have edited to provide all informations in a better way. I have telle RestKit to connect relationship based on placeIds as you can see in Favorite data mapping. But when i check the mappingResult.array in getObjectsAtPathForRelationship success block and i can't see the places in Favorite.places relationship.

Comment: Turn on trace logging and see what it says about placeIds. Which response descriptor has path pattern `user/favorite/places`? Does the mapping result contain both the favourites and places, just not connected?

Comment: @wain: this is weird. I just tested it to answer your question and looks like places are now connected to my favorite object. I may have change something but can't figure out what. To make sure i'm doing it the right way user/favorite/places response descriptor is on the places object mapping.

Comment: Whether it works may depend on what you already have in the DB when you make a request (and what that request is) - I can't tell yet...

Comment: I check before the request call and after. Before the favorite places are not linked since no places are in the DB. After the request call, the places are linked with the user favorite entity. I'll close the question and if in near future i discover that something is wrong i'll post a comment. Thank you for your support